# What are all the possible reason for IMAP Folder isn't exist

Tags: imap

I have facing one problem. While connecting to the IMAP store, we can get the number of Folders in user email account. But some folders aren't exist.

Code :

```
Folder folder = store.getFolder("Sent Items");
System.out.println(folder.exists());
folder.open(folder.READ_ONLY);
System.out.println("Got Message Subject :" + folder.getMessage(2).getSubject());
```

Result :

```
false
Got Message Subject : Test Email
```

I can able to get many folder. But some folders are not exists eventhough i can read that folder. I don't know why its happening. Please advise

Answer (score 2):

A folder doesn't have to be selectable in order to exist, and some are not. (A selectable folder is one that can contain messages.) For example, if a/b and a/c both are selectable folders, then some servers will present a parent folder called a, and depending on the server, a may be either unselectable or empty.

If a folder is selectable in general, that still doesn't mean *you* can select it. The access control list may be such that you're permitted to see the name of the folder but not its contents.

Comment: Being a StackOverflow IMAP question answerer is such a thankless job :-(

Comment: @jstedfast: now that you say it, it is a bit odd. I mean, I don't think any of the IMAP answerers *care* about getting reputation points, but it is rather puzzling that so few IMAP-related answers are accepted.